# SVProgressHUD how to delay for specified amount of time

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactivityindicatorview, svprogresshud

I am using 3rd part UIActivityIndicator SVProgressHUD, I am initalising this when my view loads. I would like to delay the activityIndicator for about 1 second while a few things in my app happen. then call [SVProgressHUD dismiss]; based off that 1 second wait.. but am not sure how to do this.

currently this is how my code looks in viewdidload

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
    [SVProgressHUD setStatus:@"loading..."];   

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

I know that there is a dismisswithsucsess:timer .. but this seems to delay the amount of time the sucsess message appears for which I don't want.. I want to delay the indicator and have no text.. but just cannot think of a way to do it.

I have tried

```
sleep(1); //which dosnt work
```

also I have tried

```
//[SVProgressHUD performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

and put [SVProgressHUD dismiss]; inside stopAnimating method but this falls over as it seems all of the calls need to be inside the same method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a timer to set of a method that dismisses your view like so:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self
selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

With method:

```
-(void)myMethod:(NSTimer*)timer {
     // Dismiss your view
     [progressthingy dismiss];  
}
```

Comment: I edited the post, so you know how your method should look like

Comment: yup, its just they have a timer restricting me on accepting within a certain period of time.. so I went and had lunch and came back and marked it for you :) cheers again!